# Python: Asyncio NATS.io blocking

Tags: python, python-asyncio, nats.io

I have troubles to make Python Asyncio NATS.io running sequentialy. I have two classes: `Account` and `Bridge`
Account holds the logic of application and it is communicating thought `Bridge` with external service via NATS.io.

`Main` file:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
account = Account(loop, options)
asyncio.async(account.start())
loop.run_forever()
```

`Account` class:

```
class Account:
    bridge = Bridge()

    def connect(self):
        result = self.bridge.connect(self.id)
        return result
```

`Bridge` class:

```
def connect(self, account_id):
    data = None

    try:
        response = yield from self.nc.timed_request("bank.account.connect",
                     BankRequest(
                          method="connect",
                          data={...}
                    ), 10)
        data = json.loads(response.data.decode())
    except ErrTimeout:
        status = Messages.REQUEST_TIMED_OUT

    return Result(data=data)
```

I need to call `account.connect()` from anywhere inside account class and get result of connection (sequentialy). now I'm getting `generator` object

Answer (score 1):

your `connect()` methods should probably be coroutines:

```
class Account:
    bridge = Bridge() # you probably want to put this in `def __init__(self)`!

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def connect(self):
        result = yield from self.bridge.connect(self.id)
        return result

class Bridge:
    @asyncio.coroutine
    def connect(self, account_id):
        data = None

        try:
            response = yield from self.nc.timed_request("bank.account.connect",
                         BankRequest(
                              method="connect",
                              data={...}
                        ), 10)
            data = json.loads(response.data.decode())
        except ErrTimeout:
            status = Messages.REQUEST_TIMED_OUT

        return Result(data=data)
```

and:

```
resp = yield from account.connect()
```